# Hey guys, Is there a way to add a init.sql file to my Docker Swarm stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Another question, how to set the name of the volume in my stack, because when I run the following command: **docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml mysql**
it adds automatically **mysql_**  to the name of the volume.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/my_file_secret
    secrets:
      - my_file_secret
secrets:
  my_file_secret:
    file: ./my_file_secret.txt
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Does it matter?  You can't directly interact with the contents of the volume; in general Compose will prefix names of things (containers and networks too) with its current project name, and if you do need to work with one of these things, there are `docker-compose` wrapper commands that use the names from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a volume name by adding `name:`

```
volumes:
  data:
    name: VOLUME_NAME
```

> The name is used as is and will not be scoped with the stack name

see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name

But as suggested in the first comment - it doesn't really matter.